# Relative layout how to align to other element instead of parent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a relative layout where i already aligned almost all elements like i want, but there are two elements at the right bottom(textView and the icon of forbiden photo), they are aligned related to the parent, the parent is not the photo.

I want to align those elements to the bottom of the image that i have:

here is a [image: screenshot]

expected results:[image: image2]

the rectangle is where i want the textView and the camera forbiden icon!

**and here is the xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_specie_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/Avaliation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Avalie a fotografia" />

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/base"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cameraForbiden"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reportImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/color_cursor_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/plantPhoto"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                />


            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/starIcon"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plantName"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cameraForbiden"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_no_photos"
                android:layout_below="@id/plantPhoto"
                />

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/base"
                android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userIcon"
                android:paddingLeft="10px"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post a picture of your expected result

Comment: updated question!

Comment: Instead of using `layout_alignParentBottom` use `layout_alignBottom`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                    />

              <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/plantName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```